# get GPS coordinates via bluetooth with python on OSX

Tags: python, bluetooth, geolocation, gps

I just bought a GPS bluetooth receiver, which has been correctly paired with my OSX machine. Now I would like to query the device for my position with python. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your GPS receiver works over a virtual COM port, so it's independent of bluetooth.

Probably these libraries will help you:

- [Python bindings](http://www.perrygeo.net/wordpress/?p=13) for gpsd (which is available for Mac too)
- [PyGPS](http://www.pygps.org/), untested

Answer (score 1):

with a virtual COM port you can use this script with the NMEA 0183 protocol http://miguellopes.net/bluetooth-gps-python/ (it's in portuguese but google translator can give you a help there)